# java String split + patterns

Tags: java, string, split, design-patterns

I'm using this method to split some text:

```
String[] parts = sentence.split("[,\\s\\-:\\?\\!\\«\\»\\'\\´\\`\\\"\\.\\\\\\/]");
```

Which will split me the text according to the specified symbols. One of the symbols is "-", because my text have weird things like this: "-------------- words --- words2 --words3--words4". Which will match my needs because it wont divide like this (in case i dont add "-"): "---words3---words4 (which will be considered a word in case i dont add "-").

But there is a tricky thing. I want to allow words like this: "aaa-bbb", which is is verified by this pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<![A-Za-z-])[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+(?![A-Za-z-])");
```

allow: aaa-bb, aaa-bbbbbbb
not allow: aaa--bb, aa--bbb-cc

So my question is, is it possible to split my text applying the split above, but also considering this pattern is a word separator(for words like aaa-bbb) ?

Thanks in advances,
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather you are after the following:

```
String[] parts = sentence.split(/[\-]{2,}/);
```